# Play with Reactive Slick with jdbc asyn or jdbc (blocking by default)?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.0, reactive-programming

Recently lightbend.com released Slick 3.x, the release candidate for “Reactive Slick”. Reactive Slick has many new features like Support for Reactive Streams API, a new API for composing and executing database actions and many .

I have two option to choose the jdbc driver

1. "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"
2. "com.github.mauricio" %% "postgresql-async" % "0.2.20"

Any suggestion which one is good (driver async or normal) to create the fully reactive application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Slick` its better to use `"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"` normal postgres driver as Slick plays well with it.

`Slick` makes db interactions asynchronous and reactive so it doesn't need another `async driver` normal driver works as expected for `Slick`.

Lot of projects have been using normal driver with Slick and are quite successful.

Comment: and do you have any recommendation  if I am not using slick?

Comment: @steve .... slick is backed by play community and is quite actively development and is highly recommended.

Comment: but even though slick 3 is reactive, JDBC is not, so it will still block threads, won't it?